# Videojs Playback rate menu button not showing in control bar

Tags: video.js

I'm fairly new to videojs but I upgraded a project with videojs to v7.17.0

Defined the playback rate in the options

```
videojs(
    'my_video', 
    {
    techOrder: ["youtube"],
    playbackRates: [0.5, 0.75, 1],
    children: [
         "mediaLoader",
         "posterImage",
         "textTrackDisplay",
         "loadingSpinner",
         "bigPlayButton",
         "controlBar",
         "errorDisplay",
         "textTrackSettings",
         "resizeManager"
    ],
    sources: [
        {
             "type": "video/youtube",
             "src": 'video_url'
        }
    ],
    controlBar: {
         pictureInPictureToggle: false
    }
    }
)
```

This didn't add the playback rate menu in the control bar. So I did some test in the browser console itself

```
player.controlBar.addChild('playbackRateMenuButton')
e {player_: o, isDisposed_: false, parentComponent_: t, options_: {…}, id_: 'my_video_component_5045', …}
```

This suggests that menu button was added but still no button in the control bar itself.

I also tried this with the pictureInpicture toggle menu and it does add it to the controlbar but not the playback rate menu

Anyone know a fix for this?

P.S. I tried to define `playbackRateMenuButton: true` in the `controlBar` option as well which throws a `RangeError: Invalid array length`

Comment: It works with the exact options you've used above: https://codepen.io/mister-ben/pen/mdBwwmO?editors=1000

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens "data-setup" is passed in the video tag, in that case, the  options passed while initializing is not applied. Removing data-setup from HTML must work.

```html
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    data-setup="{}" // Remove this from code.
  >
```

Comment: I do not have the data-setup attribute in the video tag. All the options for the player are set up through JS